# Venn diagram, is C = (A ∩ B ∩ C)?

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I just saw a Venn diagram that has:

A = All integer numbers between 1 and 100 that is dividable by 2.
B = All integer numbers between 1 and 100 that is dividable by 3.
C = All integer numbers between 1 and 100 that is dividable by 5.

And it asks what is:

$$(A ∩ B) - C$$

My first thought was:

$$(A ∩ B) - C = \frac{100}{2*3} - 20 = -4$$

And the solution manual then suggested:

$$(A ∩ B) - C = \frac{100}{2*3} - \frac{100}{2*3*5} = 13$$

Does not this imply that that:

$$C = (A ∩ B ∩ C)$$

Why is this so? I thought C was 100/5 = 20..

Is it just a convention that this is what is meant? Because it makes sense to only subtract the part of C that is in (A ∩ B), but this does not make C = (A ∩ B ∩ C) does it?

Comment: $|A-B|=|A|-|A\cap B|$ think about that relation.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

$(A ∩ B) - C$, means all elements in both $A$ and $B$ and not in$C$. All elements dividable by 6 and not dividable by 5.
The elements of $(A ∩ B) - C$ are of the form $6n$ where $n=1,2,3,4,6,7,9,11,12,13,14,16$

Answer (score 1):

The minus sign here actually means set minus. That is
$$
  E-F=\{x\in E: x\notin F\}
$$

Comment: What if we have + C instead? No difference then?